# What exactly is the function of VDD_IO pin?

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, embedded

I see in many ICs 2 sets of volatge, VDD and VDD_IO. VDD is the core voltage,VDD_IO is the I/O interface voltage.

What exactly is the function of VDD-IO volatge?

1. Does it supply power to I/O drivers?
2. Does it serve only as the reference voltage level for 'High'?

In one datasheet I read VDD_IO pin does not supply power, instead it acts as the VIH reference.
[Power meter IC- Page 14](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/PAC1931-Family-Data-Sheet-DS20005850E.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This information is in the datasheet of the particular IC so you should always check before actually using it.

But generally, Vddio supplies the input output logic and thus determines the LO and HI output voltages as well as the LO and HI input voltage thresholds.

Comment: Just to add, it is not uncommon for devices to have multiple VDD pins, named different things (like VDD and VDDIO) that drive different things, but have to be at the same voltage. This would mean that you couldn't have VDD at 3.3V and VDDIO at 5V, for example. For this reason, you should always check the datasheet to find out not just what the pins power, but the limits on them